# Motorcycle downshifts are becoming more difficult - do I have a gearbox issue?

Tags: gears, harley-davidson

I have a 2011 CVO Harley Davidson Ultra glide with a 6 speed gearbox, and while it has always been a little clunky (it's a Harley tourer, not a Yamaha sport bike) recently I have been noticing a new issue:

When slowing down for a junction,  I used to be able to come to a stop in 3rd with the clutch in, and then kick down to first while stationary, but if I try that now, the kick will not engage and the bike will stay in 3rd. Releasing the clutch a little so the bike starts to pull does let me downshift.

So I have been taking to downshifting as I'm decelerating - which certainly feels more natural, and is more like I would do in a car - blip the throttle and downshift with only minimal clutch, but training guidance from motorcycle groups seems to indicate that this is wrong and I should be coming to a halt and then downshifting the final couple of gears.

I can't imagine I'm doing any harm - other than maybe some clutch or gear wear if I get my gearshifts very badly wrong - but is the fact I'm needing to do this now a symptom of something failing in the gearbox?

Comment: I'm wondering if you just need some clutch adjustment.

Comment: Try lubing the clutch.

Comment: I have found that the oil in the transmission can have a significant effect on the ease of shifting in many bikes.  So before you assume it's bad or failing, you might try using a different brand of oil and see if that help.  Be sure the type is proper as specified in your owners manual.